# How to disable Chrome download blocking feature?

Tags: google-chrome, zip

Recently, I tried to download this [zip file](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/releases/download/v1.4.0/jd-gui-windows-1.4.0.zip) with Chrome v72.0.3626.121.
Chrome simply deleted the file as soon as it downloaded it.

A mere message informed me that "Chrome has blocked jd-gui-windows-1.4.0.zip, because this file may be dangerous.". I did a quick search ending up on a [Google support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6261569?hl=en).

This page explains why some downloads may be blocked. Among the proposed reasons, I spotted this one: *"We think it might be a malicious, unwanted, or uncommon file."*

So I sent this file to virustotal.com. You may check the [detailed produced report](https://www.virustotal.com/fr/url/7b6e4c3efccdd3f7c43aa3be3096f63366596e9608908c966aabedc4539022ed/analysis/1551547370/). virustotal.com didn't find any problem with this file. On my side, I use the program in the zip regularly for years.

How can I disable this Chrome feature?

Comment: [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+disable+Chrome+download+blocking+feature%3F) led to essentially the same fix (slightly different wording from an older version). And you're shunning google & haven't switched away from Chrome yet, at least to Chromium?

Comment: @Xen2050 The computer I use Chrome is not mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution #1**

> 1. Click on the "View Site Information" button on the left side of the URL (Padlock Icon) and click "Site Settings".
> 2. Set Insecure Content to "Allow" and it will no longer block downloads from that site.

**Solution #2**

You can also whitelist entire websites via Chrome's settings:

> 1. Settings > Security and Privacy > Site Settings > Insecure Content.
> 2. Under Allowed to show insecure content click "Add" and enter the main website URL and click "Add".

**Solution #3**

Here is how I did:

> 1. Go to chrome://settings or just click on the settings icon on the dashboard.
> 2. Scroll to the bottom of the settings page and click on `Show advanced settings`
> 3. Under advanced settings, find the subsection called `Privacy and Security`.
>    Then look turn off the option `Protect you and your device from dangerous sites`.

=> You can now download anything from Internet **AT YOUR OWN RISK** !

=> You can turn back on the option.

Reference:

https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-the-dangerous-download-blocked-error-in-chrome/

Comment: While this works and possibly the only option this is totally braindead because the old dangerous sites protection was useful while this download blocker is totally hamfisted.

Comment: It seems that this option is no longer available, at least for the  moment. On Windows, for me, there is no section called `Privacy and Security` under `Advanced` settings anymore, and the settings under the main `Privacy and Security` section offer no agency here. I set my `Safe Browsing` setting to "No Protection", but still, no luck.

Answer (score 7):

Just a workaround per file...: Hit CTRL+J and per downloaded file you can indicate if you want to keep it anyway (or not..). I know that's a workaround, but it's at least more safe than turning off protection.

Comment: Sometimes you want things to work, not to be secure

Comment: That option wasn't available to me

Comment: This is the best option I have found so far. I prefer keeping safe browsing on most of the time and I didn't realise that the downloads tab gave the option to keep the file.